# PHP Socket Server doesn't work with client, error permission at socket_bind()

Tags: java, php, websocket

I have shared hosting "ad-box.deslab.vn". The following code is in web server:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
* as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '181.224.157.142';
$port = 80;

// Create Socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($sock === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
if (!socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) { 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
 exit; 
}

// Bind socket to port
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// Start listening for connection
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// Handling connection from client
do {
    $msgsock = socket_accept($sock); // msgsock is a client connect to webserver
    if ($msgsock === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }

    $request ="PHP said : you are sent " . socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ);
    socket_write($msgsock, $request, strlen($request));
    socket_close($msgsock);  // Close connect of client
} while (true);
socket_close($sock);  // Close socket of server
```

?>

In the client side, program was wrote in Java. Following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class WebClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String host ="ad-box.deslab.vn";

    Socket s = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket(host, 80);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname\n");
    }
    // Send message to server
    String message = "FETEL HCMUS";
    // String message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    // System.out.println(message);
    bw.write(message);
    bw.flush();
    // Get response from server
    String response = "";
    while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    bw.close();
    br.close();
    s.close();
}
```

}

When I run index.php file by web browser. Browser show this error:

Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [13]: Permission denied in /home/vietchip/public_html/deslab.vn/ad-box/index.php on line 26
socket_bind() failed: reason: Permission denied socket_bind() failed: reason: Permission denied

Can anyone help me to fix it?
Thanks so much.

Comment: You can't bind to 80 unless you're root. Pick a port number > 1024.

Comment: I have try with port > 1024,. However client can't connect to server. what is  another method else? Because, I read somewhere that: if it is shared host, only port 80 and 443 open.